# MU-SURF implementation in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, surf, ros

Is there an implementation of MU-SURF descriptor for OpenCV? I'm using the Star Detector which is based on CenSuRe. 
I'm making a monocular visual odometry system for a mobile robot with ROS and OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can use the OpenSURF implementation of MU-SURF available here https://code.google.com/p/opensurf1/source/browse/trunk/OpenSURFcpp/src/surf.cpp